# How to display length of matching strings from JSON data?

Tags: jquery

image below is the console result. Let say I want to print result for `department` which contain vary answers (example 1A, 2B, 3C). So how to know the length of each inside `department`? The length of 1A, the length of 2B and so on.

[image]

[image]

I am trying do like this but error.

```
var department = response.data[0].department['1A'].length;
console.log(department)
$("#department").text(department);

var department2 = response.data[0].department['1B'].length;
console.log(department2)
$("#department2").text(department2);
```

JSON

```
{
  "status": "Success",
  "data": [
    {
      "user_id": 3,
      "address_line1": null,
      "address_line2": null,
      "country": null,
      "date_of_birth": null,
      "department": "1A",
      "district": null,
      "gender": "Male",
      "workgroup": "AM",
      "name": "Michael"
    },
    {
      "user_id": 4,
      "address_line1": null,
      "address_line2": null,
      "country": null,
      "date_of_birth": null,
      "department": "2B",
      "district": null,
      "gender": "Male",
      "workgroup": "MGR",
      "name": "Mike"
    },
    {
      "user_id": 5,
      "address_line1": null,
      "address_line2": null,
      "country": null,
      "date_of_birth": null,
      "department": "3C",
      "district": null,
      "gender": "Female",
      "workgroup": "AGM",
      "name": "Rachel"
    },
    {
      "user_id": 6,
      "address_line1": null,
      "address_line2": null,
      "country": null,
      "date_of_birth": null,
      "department": "3C",
      "district": null,
      "gender": "Male",
      "workgroup": "AGM",
      "name": "Joe"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: How does that path `response.data[0].user_privilege['1A'].length;` match `response.data[0].department`?

Comment: Please include a more complete sample of your data as text, not as an image of text. You can use `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2))`.

Comment: sorry I have correct my posting.

Comment: Add the complete JSON response please.

Comment: I have update the json. it is sufficient?

Comment: The department you are trying to access is not an `array` its just a string. So it will not have a `length` - Are you just trying to show the department name as a text ?

Comment: No, I want to know the length because I want to display as numbering only just like a statistic summary. I have update my posting again.

Comment: so you mean the `length` of the department string?

Comment: Sorry! but your question is very unclear on what you are to achieve. Can you simple explain how you will have deparment showing as `5` from your JSON

Comment: I get what you mean now. See the working solution below exactly as you wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function on your `response.data` to count the specific `strings` you have it your `JSON` data using `.length`

Run snippet below to see the `counts` for each department.

```js
var response = {
  "status": "Success",
  "data": [{
      "user_id": 3,
      "address_line1": null,
      "address_line2": null,
      "country": null,
      "date_of_birth": null,
      "department": "1A",
      "district": null,
      "gender": "Male",
      "workgroup": "AM",
      "name": "Michael"
    },
    {
      "user_id": 4,
      "address_line1": null,
      "address_line2": null,
      "country": null,
      "date_of_birth": null,
      "department": "2B",
      "district": null,
      "gender": "Male",
      "workgroup": "MGR",
      "name": "Mike"
    },
    {
      "user_id": 5,
      "address_line1": null,
      "address_line2": null,
      "country": null,
      "date_of_birth": null,
      "department": "3C",
      "district": null,
      "gender": "Female",
      "workgroup": "AGM",
      "name": "Rachel"
    },
    {
      "user_id": 6,
      "address_line1": null,
      "address_line2": null,
      "country": null,
      "date_of_birth": null,
      "department": "3C",
      "district": null,
      "gender": "Male",
      "workgroup": "AGM",
      "name": "Joe"
    }
  ]
}

let count1 = response.data.filter(x => x.department == '1A').length;
let count2 = response.data.filter(x => x.department == '2B').length;
let count3 = response.data.filter(x => x.department == '3C').length;

console.log(count1)
console.log(count2)
console.log(count3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your json, within your `data` you have a list of objects, and you're trying to find the length of one of the strings (department) inside this object. The way you've worded the question is a little confusing, but I think this is what you are aiming to do:

```js
var department = response.data[0].department.length;
console.log(department)
$("#department").text(department);
```

According to the JSON you've provided, `department` is not an array, if it was an array then the JSON would look like this for each object within `data`:

```js
    {
      "user_id": 3,
      "address_line1": null,
      "address_line2": null,
      "country": null,
      "date_of_birth": null,
      "department": [ "1A", "2A", "3A" ],
      "district": null,
      "gender": "Male",
      "workgroup": "AM",
      "name": "Michael"
    },
```

I also think you're misunderstanding what `length` does? `length` returns the number of characters in the string, meanwhile the image you have implies that you are trying to get the number for the department out of the value that `department` is set to. If the format of each department is consistent, then you can simply do a substring to get just the first character of the `department` like this:

```js
var departmentNumber = response.data[0].department.substring(0, 0);
```

or with `charAt()` like this:

```js
var departmentNumber = response.data[0].department.charAt(0);
```

This would only take the first character from the string, meaning you get the department number that you are potentially after.

I would recommend, if you can, that you provide a different variable in addition to `department` - something like `departmentNum` - to save the need to perform a selection from a string like this.

Comment: Hi, I replied from Satpal answers above. something like that.